# Multiple form submissions sequentially for both success and failure - with Rails And Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a problem with my current app. I have a form and it's broken into three steps. Each step is hidden with a CSS class that basically hides one group and reveals another after a button click. As it stands right now if a user forgets to enter their CC number in the field and tries to submit the form it sends them back to the first part of the process with all the form submissions deleted.

I need it to behave like this: If a user makes an error filling out the form, the app should give them an error message on the part of the form they are on and persist the form submissions. This is against Rails natural behavior so how can I accomplish this. With JS? or Ajax? I'm really not sure where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup on my app, I think the best way to do this is with a plugin like [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). This way your data is checked client-side before getting sent back to the server. Here is an [article](https://djaodjin.com/blog/jquery-multi-step-validation.blog.html) that helped me when I set up my site.

The only issue that I ran into with this tutorial is that if someone presses the enter key before fully finishing the form, it submits the data to the database for verification and returns errors. To avoid this I disable the default value of the enter key so that users have to manually click the 'next' and 'submit' buttons.

Feel free to look [here](http://truevolution.org/hcpb#section5) for how I implemented it on a site, and ask me any questions you might have after looking at the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be digging back into this tomorrow and I may have some questions.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong..there are three different forms,each one coming and getting submitted one at a time.

So there is a good catch for this scenario.----

1. Make three different **post** request like `users/posts/form_1,users/posts/form_2 and users/posts/form_3` each having a new entry in `routes.rb` posting the form to the controller.

   **Note** - *one controller with same action handling all forms post request* **using different params**

Example of `posts_controller.rb`:-

```
     ##this will be used to load the first form out of 3 forms.
     ##this is a get request
     get"post/get_form" => 'post#get_form'

     ##this is post and not get request.      
     post "post/form_submit" => 'post#post_form'
```

2. Now,every form will be in `app/views/posts/form_submit_1,app/views/posts/form_submit_2 and app/views/posts/form_submit_3` and `get` request to load the form will load `app/views/posts/form_submit_1` by default.

As we will be `posting` every form,every form must have a unique hidden field containing some parameter like :-

```
          <!-- we are using custom path to submit form,hence add url in form tag -->
          <%= form_for(@post,:url=>users_post_form_submit_path) do |f| %>

          <!-- this will be used to identify the forms at the controller after posting.so every form will have form_submit_1,form_submit_ and form_submit_3 -->
          <input type="hidden"  name="form_submit_1" value=">" />


        <%end%>
```

2. In the controller,there will be just one method which will handle all forms submission.A small example can be -

   ### here we will use the hidden `form_submit_1/2/3` values posted along with the form to **recognise** what we need to do.

   ### you can **pass arguments** in the url like `posts/get_form?form_1,posts/get_form?form_2 and posts/get_form?form_3` to load your forms.

   ```
   def get_form
      ##by default first form unless changed,this variable will be used to load form depending upon its value in the view template shown below.
      @which_form = 1
      ##use the params to load forms
      ##this will load first form and this is default call 
      if params[:form_number]
        @post = User.find(params[:id])
        ##this can be form 2 or 3
        ##this wil be used to load partial view/post/_form_1,2 or 3
        @which_form = "form_submit_#{params[:form_number]}"
      else
        ##load first form by default
        @which_form = "form_submit_1"

    end


    def form_submit
        ###check the model,validate it and redirect to form_submit_2
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])       
       if params[:form_submit_1]
        if everything_ok and @post.valid? and @post.save
          ##save my objects in form 1 and move to form 2
          redirect_to post_get_form_path(:form_number => 2)
        else
         format.html { render :get_form}
         format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end             


       elsif params[:form_submit_2]
                 redirect_to post_get_form_path(:form_number => 3)


       elsif params[:form_submit_3]
               redirect_to your_path_where_you_want_to_show_sucess_message.
               flash[:now] = "Thanks for submitting the details"

       end
    end
   ```

your view in `app/views/post/get_form` will have a default partial to render else will use form_number to render other forms.

```
####an example,here @which_form,whose value by default is 1 unless changed 

render :partial => 'form_submit_#{@which_form}', :object => @post
```

This is a partial implementation of seqUential form submission just like form wizard.This might help you to get some idea of what to do.YOu may change it the way you want that is best suited to you.Moreover @post can be different model to..all you need to do is pass it to the view if its valid or saved else redirect to default form.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just actually did this sort of set up for a new feature I was building at work. I broke it into individual .ajax posts to the specific controllers I needed. Each section had to update multiple things but conditions to the previous information.

I just used inputs and used the .val() of them whenever I needed to post new information. I used important information that was hidden to the client but was needed for an update during the process.

I just posted all of my things to the update method on all of them. I didn't do many things in the back end. I mostly converted and changed any information I needed to customize before I sent it.

I took it a step further and created safe guards that if the information for the first section was updated in the last 2 hours, then it would pull that information and they could skip the first or second step if they happen to reload their page or loose service during the process. I just checked it inside the $(document).ready() and set them to the .val() of the inputs and hide the steps they had already filled in.